# NLog DiagnosticListener for DiagnosticSource

Tags: .net, nlog, system.diagnostics

Is there any package for NLog that offers native integration into the log .NET DiagnosticSource model? Kind of like NLogTraceListener...

Don’t see anything on google at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just perform DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe and then forward to an NLog-Logger:

```
            DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe(delegate(DiagnosticListener listener)
            {
                // subscribe to the Service Bus DiagnosticSource
                if (listener.Name == "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus")
                {
                    // receive event from Service Bus DiagnosticSource
                    listener.Subscribe(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, object> @event)
                    {
                        // Log operation details once it's done
                        if (!@event.Key.EndsWith("Stop"))
                            return;
                        var currentActivity = Activity.Current;
                        NLogLogger.Debug($"{currentActivity.OperationName} Duration: {currentActivity.Duration}\n\t{string.Join("\n\t", currentActivity.Tags)}");
                    });
                }
            });
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/DiagnosticSourceUsersGuide.md#discovery-of-diagnosticlisteners

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/develop/Src/Web/Web/AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule.cs

Example of setting up Observer (Listener that you want):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.DiagnosticSource/blob/master/test/NLog.DiagnosticSource.Tests/DiagnosticListenerTargetTests.cs

That listens for the output from a Target (opposite way):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.DiagnosticSource/blob/master/src/NLog.DiagnosticSource/Targets/DiagnosticListenerTarget.cs

Comment: I was hoping for something more pre-canned that would auto add the kvps as contextual properties, but wouldn't be hard that way either.

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for what ApplicationInsights DiagnosticListener does - I want the application insights telemetry to go to NLog instead

Comment: @Jeff maybe you can find inspiration from the AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule (Updated answer with link to source). Also performs `DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe`

Comment: Right - I don’t want to rewrite all that code myself. I just want to do structured logging from DiagnosticSources

Comment: Sometimes it can be fun to build your own lego pieces, instead of just complaining about those lying on the floor :)